# How do I get the count of non matching cells in a row between two sheets?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have two sheets, Sheet A containing a truth table like such:

```
    A B C D E
Foo T F F T F
Bar T F F F F
```

Sheet B contains another table:

```
A B C D E
T F F T F
```

I need to add a column to table A counting how many cells match the corresponding cell in sheet B, as such:

```
Foo T F F T F 2
Bar T F F F F 1
```

Best I could come up with for the first count cell was

```
=COUNTIF(B2:F2,B2:F2=INDIRECT("sheet-b!A2:E2"))
```

but this gives me `0` even though it should be 2.

*Edit:*
I was able to come up with this, which correctly counts the number of differing cells:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:F2=INDIRECT("sheet-b!A2:E2"),1,0)))
```

The next thing I want is to add an AND statement, and count the cell if it matches or if the `sheet-b` cell is F:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND("F"=INDIRECT("sheet-b!A2:E2"),B5:F5=INDIRECT("sheet-b!A2:E2")),1,0)))
```

However it doesn't seem like i can use an AND statement in this formula. Even the following gives a sum of zero:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(TRUE,B2:F2=INDIRECT("sheet-b!A2:E2")),1,0)))
```

how come?

*Edit2*: [Link to example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V2dHzqWzBStg3NmJEXuTzuhw2g929IJkqYFPEH2cDfM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I get the count of non-matching cells in a row between two sheets

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), 
 MMULT(IF(B2:F='sheet-b'!A2:E2, 0, 1), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:F2)^0)), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I had to slightly tweak my query (like I wrote in my update), and to get exactly the result I'm looking for I would need to figure out why `=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(TRUE,B2:F2=INDIRECT("sheet-b!A2:E2")),1,0)))` doesn't do what I expect.

Comment: `AND` and `OR` are not supported in `ARRAYFORMULA`. you need to use `*`/`+` to convert it in 0/1 logic

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A<>"", COUNTIFS(TRIM(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet2!J1:N),,999^99))),
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B1:F)       ,,999^99))), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This doesn't work (after modifying the query to match the example sheet i posted above, i get all zeroes)

Comment: this solution accounts the row values as an individual set not as standalone values within a set of row